# Excel VBA editor strange behavior

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue with the Excel 365 VBA editor. When I first open Excel and go to to the editor, I can type as normal but if I open one of my workbooks it acts strangely.

I cannot type spaces at the end of a line. If I type `function` it appears in red like something is wrong, when before opening the workbook it would appear black and let me continue to type.

If I type a function `isTest` for example and I type `istest=` in the body of the function, it will appear in red without spaces but as soon as I type a character it will appear as `isTest = f` (typing the letter "f" for example) with the spaces automatically inserted and the cursor automatically placed after the "t" in isTest and formatted with an uppercase "T" like I already completed the line and it formatted it.

Any idea what might be going on and how I can stop this behavior?

Comment: *"I open one of my workbooks"* Does this workbook run any code automatically? Is there a `Workbook_Open` event? If so please [edit] your question and add the code of this event.

Comment: No. I even copied the data to a separate workbook and re-saved it to no avail. I am wondering if this had to do with the last 365 update as one happened recently..

Comment: I may have stumbled on to something. I renamed the open document to .xslm and the issue instantly disappeared. I have to experiment further. I am not sure why that should effect the entire editor and specifically Personal.xlsb.

Comment: When I said rename, I meant resaved. Also, from what I am seeing now, as long as there is one file open with the macro extension, .xlsm, then others with .xlsx can be open and the editor continues to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the reason for this behavior of not being ale to work on macros in Personal.xlsb, I found a work around. What I do is save an empty workbook to be macro enabled (.xlsm) and then when I want to use the editor properly I go to that workbook and that alt-tab to the editor and it works again as long as the active workbook in Excel is a macro enabled workbook. I don't know why this is but at least I get a working editor again.